# why css file was damaged on server

Tags: css, plesk

I have a problem with my style.css file.
after i published it on plesk server, it worked fine. but some times, (such as when press Ctrl+F5 ) or simple refresh, it's content is unreadable.
I attach an screenshot .
how to fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
it's about `gzip` function that not worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a encoding mismatch. Make sure that the client and server are using UTF-8 to encode the file. If that does not work it might be a error while sending/receiving the file. If you are on Chrome, use the network tab in the Chrome dev tools to check that out.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I used utf-8 encoding, but the problem was about the gzip function that not worked fine.